# How big can insects be before falling into kashrut halacha?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, bugs

So we typically clean vegetable matter of bugs because, while it isn't an aveirah to eat a bug part if it's smaller than a(n) (halachic) olive, it is still prohibited to eat any non-kosher living thing as a whole regardless of size. How far does this extend though? Obviously we aren't concerned with microbacteria because those are impossible to see with the naked eye, but what are the machmir and makil opinions on this subject? How big does the bug have to be before it is required, by these opinions, to brush them off your veggies?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the rule is "visible to the naked eye," but I don't have a source for you.

Comment: @Shokhet That's the thought I had as well, but it's a little subjective... kind of like the size of said olive.

Comment: About the size of the kezayis: http://www.amazon.com/Halachos-Kzayis-Yisroel-Pinchos-Bodner/dp/1583304894/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1393562492&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=kezayis

Comment: @Shokhet You are correct. The standard is: large enough to see with the naked eye in optimal conditions (i.e. a person with excellent vision, examining in the sunlight against a contrasting background). See also [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37620/halibut-scales-how-to-identify-them#comment98939_37628), [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37620/halibut-scales-how-to-identify-them#comment99189_37628), and [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27205/whats-the-best-way-to-dip-maror-into-charoset-if-youre-using-horseradish#comment63545_27205).

Comment: "...while it isn't an aveirah to eat a bug part if it's smaller than a(n) (halachic) olive...." That is incorrect. It is biblically prohibited to eat even a bug smaller than a *k'zayis*, and the person is theoretically biblically liable for lashes if such a bug was eaten intact (Rambam [*Hil. Ma'achalos Asuros* 2:21](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=4597)).

Comment: We aren't concerned about microbacteria because they're not bugs, not because they're hard to see.

Comment: @Fred Bug *part* As in, a bug leg or a bug head. Not an in tact bug.

Comment: @rosenjcb Oh, I somehow missed that, probably because there's every reason to expect that there are intact bugs on infested vegetables, and the logical part of my brain overpowered the careful reading part of my brain. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: (Also, to clarify: By "excellent vision" I didn't mean someone with unusually acute vision, but rather what is considered standard among people with good, unimpaired vision).

Comment: @Fred If it's visible but not visibly a bug, how is that prohibited? No one could have known it was a bug until the last few centuries.

Comment: @Shokhet More about the size of the kezayis: http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2010/03/evolution-of-olive.html

Comment: @DoubleAA I'll take a look, thanks for the link!

Comment: @DoubleAA If experts could visually recognize a particular specimen as such under optimal circumstances, that may be sufficient to be considered visible. In the [article linked by Loewian](http://5tjt.com/tropicana-orange-juice-an-update/), Rabbi Hoffman said R' Elyashiv considered it a *chumra* to forbid a bug that is visible to the naked eye but only identifiable as a bug via a lens (likely based on your reasoning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any positions that forbid that which can't be detected using means that were available in ancient times (e.g. microscopic); nor of a position that would allow one to take an individual bug that is visibly a bug, albeit small, and eat it (or frankly, l'chatchila, even an individual bug part that is not part of a larger mixture).  There is a range of positions, however, about when it is a concern in a taaroves (mixture) regarding how evident the bugs' presence have to be. See: http://5tjt.com/tropicana-orange-juice-an-update/

Comment: Very interesting article!