# Permitting Aguna Via Dream

Tags: sources-mekorot, dream, aguna

The [MeshivasNefesh Chelek Even Haezer, Takanat Agunot 35.7](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15108&st=&pgnum=91&hilite=) is quoted as permitting an aguna based on the combination of factors including a mother saying her son appeared in a dream saying he drowned and mentioned the area of the river.

Are there others who disagree with this ruling?

*Note: CYLOR who will then call his gadol*

Comment: Umdana,siman muvak?

Comment: Isnt that teshuva discussing a case where the dream gives over facts that no one could have known and then become like simanim?

Comment: It's not only because of the dream.

Comment: Right it was a tzeiruf

Comment: On halachic validity of dreams: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49710&st=&pgnum=346

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,I believe  the Noda B'Yehuda would disagree. In Yoreh Deah Tinyana siman 30 he notes that dreams are not reliable and writes " where do we ever see halacha learned from a dream!?!?".further in the teshuva he writes " to bring a proof from a dream is nonsense and nothing at all". He is discussing a case about a certain fish(barbuta) which was debatable about its status of kashrus.

Text :

[image]

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6569